# Proving Monotonic Sequence Theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

A sequence $b_n$ is decreasing and bounded. Prove it it convergent.

Proof:

Since $b_n$ is bounded, $b_n > L$ where L is the **greatest lower bound** as per the completeness Axiom.

Consider some $l>0$
We know $b_n > L + l$ is **FALSE**

Thus $b_n < L + l$ is **TRUE** for $n>N$, where N is considered a cut-off value

Rearranging $=>$ $|b_n-L|<l$ for $n>N$
$=>$ lim$b_n$ = L as $n -> infinity

Comment: We know the the sequence is monotone decreasing. Suppose we have boundedness and the sequence doesn't converge. Then we know there is always and N such that $b_{k} < b_{l}$ for $l>k$. In general for $n$ large enough we can get $b_n < -M$. The only case we consider for this to be invalid is if $\{b_n\} = c$, but then we get convergence immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\{b_n\}$ is bounded, it has an infimum call it $S_*$. Now $b_n \ge S_*$ for all $n \in N$. Now since $S_*$ is an infimum, given $\epsilon \gt 0$, there exists atleast one $n_0 \in N$  such that $S_*+ \epsilon \gt a_{n_0}$. Now for all $n \ge n_0$, $a_n \le a_{n_0} \lt S_*+ \epsilon$ . Moreover, $$S_*- \epsilon \lt s_* \le a_n \le a_{n_0} \lt S_* + \epsilon$$ for all $ n \ge n_0$. Hence given $ \epsilon \gt 0$ there exists an $n_0 \in N$ such that for all $n \ge n_0$ we have $$|a_n-S_*| \lt \epsilon$$

Comment: ..I am trying to look at analysis problems. Is my argument in the above comment valid?