# Show that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty |a_i|<\infty$ implies there is a finite number $L$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty |a_i|=L$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm not sure how to show that the partial sum will not exhibit "oscillating" behaviour. I know this will not happen because each item is positive but not sure how to argue rigorously.

Comment: The sequence of partial sums $$s_n := \sum_{i=1}^n |a_i| $$ is monotone increasing and bounded above, and hence converges to $\sup_n s_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$S_{n+1}=S_n + |a_{n+1}|\ge S_n\ge 0$$

then $S_n$ is a monotonic increasing sequences and then, since it doesn't diverge, it is bounded and we have that $ S_n  \to L$.

Refer also to [Proving Monotonic Sequence Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/850083/proving-monotonic-sequence-theorem)